# CKeditor integration with FCKeditor filebrowser

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 3 and I need to integrate a cost-free filebrowser/uploader. I tried to integrate the one that comes with FCKEditor but I [always get this XML error](http://pastie.org/743024):

> The server didn't send back a proper XML response. Please contact your system administrator.
>
> XML request error: OK (200)
>
> Requested URL: `http://example.com/admin/filemanager/browser/default/?Command=GetFoldersAndFiles&Type=File&CurrentFolder=%2F&uuid=1260817820353`
>
> Response text:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
> <html>
>  <head>
>   <title>Index of /admin/filemanager/browser/default</title>
>  </head>
>  <body>
> <h1>Index of /admin/filemanager/browser/default</h1>
> <table><tr><th><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th>
>   <th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th>
>   <th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th>
>   <th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th>
>   <th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
> <!-- edited for brevity -->
> ```

I'm trying to do it in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function(){
  CKEDITOR.config.language='es';
  CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
  CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV;
  CKEDITOR.replace('ncCont',{
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'filemanager/browser/default/browser.html',
    filebrowserUploadUrl : 'filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php'
  });
 };
</script>
```

Can FCKeditor be integrated with CKEditor? If yes, how can this be done? If not, is there a free filebrowser/uploader alternative?

Answer (score 10):

Wanted to piggy back off Penuel whose code helped me a lot.

add this to /filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php

```
// Get the CKEditor Callback
$CKEcallback = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'];

//modify the next line adding in the new param
FileUpload($sType, $sCurrentFolder, $sCommand, $CKEcallback);
```

add this to /filemanager/connectors/php/io.php

```
// This is the function that sends the results of the uploading process to CKE.
function SendCKEditorResults ($callback, $sFileUrl, $customMsg = '')
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

  $rpl = array( '\\' => '\\\\', '"' => '\\"' ) ;

  echo 'window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("'. $callback. '","'.
    strtr($sFileUrl, $rpl). '", "'. strtr( $customMsg, $rpl). '");' ; 

  echo '</script>';
}
```

modify this /filemanager/connectors/php/commands.php

```
//line 158
function FileUpload($resourceType, $currentFolder, $sCommand, $CKEcallback = '')

//line 166

  if ( (isset($_FILES['NewFile']) && !is_null($_FILES['NewFile']['tmp_name']))
    # This is for the QuickUpload tab box
    or (isset($_FILES['upload']) and !is_null($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])))
  {
    global $Config ;

    $oFile = isset($_FILES['NewFile']) ? $_FILES['NewFile'] : $_FILES['upload'];

...

  if($CKEcallback == '')
  {
    // this line already exists so wrap the if block around it
    SendUploadResults( $sErrorNumber, $sFileUrl, $sFileName ) ;
  }
  else 
  {
    //issue the CKEditor Callback
    SendCKEditorResults ($CKEcallback, $sFileUrl,
    ($sErrorNumber != 0 
      ? 'Error '. $sErrorNumber. ' upload failed. '. $sErrorMsg
      : 'Upload Successful'));
  }
```

You'll need to add the upload URL's to your CKEDITOR definition like so:

```
  var filemanager = '/js/ckeditor/filemanager/';
  var browser = filemanager + 'browser/default/browser.html';
  var connector = filemanager + 'connectors/php/connector.php';
  var upload = filemanager + 'connectors/php/upload.php';
  CKEDITOR.replace( id,
  {    
    customConfig : this.config,
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : browser +'?Connector=' + connector,
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : browser + '?Type=Image&Connector='
      + connector,
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : browser + '?Type=Flash&Connector=' 
      + connector,
    filebrowserUploadUrl : upload + '?type=Files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl : upload + '?type=Images',
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : upload + '?type=Flash'
  });
```

I think that covers everything left off by Penuel

Comment: I followed this guide (above), but after selecting an image to upload and pressing "send to server", I always get "Cannot POST /filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?type=Images&amp;CKEditor=htmlSlide0&amp;CKEditorFuncNum=0&amp;langCode=de" I assume the "&" get replaced with "&amp" which breakes the string, but I cannot find the code that does that (don't know php). Any help/advice?

Answer (score 8):

To answer your question I have posted one small tutorial on my blog with step by step instructions to integrate the File Browser of FCKEditor in CKEditor. Please goto:

http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/

I have done this for PHP connector but should be pretty simple for other languages as well.

You can also download the already done example or view the demo from this article.

Comment: I followed this guide, but after selecting an image to upload and pressing "send to server", I always get "Cannot POST /filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?type=Images&amp;CKEditor=htmlSlide0&amp;CKEditorFuncNum=0&amp;langCode=de" I assume the "&" get replaced with "&amp" which breakes the string, but I cannot find the code that does that (don't know php). Any help/advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a custom file browser with my implementation of ckeditor, so I don't see why you couldn't use the old file browser. It uses the same javascript to populate the editor.

Just install the old FCK editor in whatever directory, and make sure you have the correct path to that browser in your config. I'm guessing that you have a pathing problem above.