# CKEditor filebrowser plugin

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

Can anyone explain with examples for everyone how to integrate CKEditor and external file browser? Where to put this code:

```
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/browser/browse.php',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/uploader/upload.php'
});
```

And what shoud return these:

```
browse.php
upload.php
```

I think the answer for this question should be [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload). So many peeople asked this question, but there is no definitive guide to this plugin. SO members, maybe some of you can?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKeditor integration with FCKeditor filebrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903510/ckeditor-integration-with-fckeditor-filebrowser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filebrowserBrowseUrl` will be the url of a page that allows a user to choose a file on the server. This page will be opened in a new window.
These arguments will be added to the url `CKEditor=editor&CKEditorFuncNum=2&langCode=en-gb`

- CKEditor is the current editor
- CKEditorFuncNum is the function to call(pass this value to `callFunction`)
- langCode is the language

in the popup window call

```js
window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(CKEditorFuncNum, 'img_url');
```

to set the selected image and optionally `window.close();` to close the window.
e.g.

```php
<?php
$files = glob('/images/directory/*.{jpg,png,gif,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE);
if (count($files) > 0){
    echo 'Select a file <ul>';
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo '<li><button onclick="select(this)" data-name="'.$file.'">.basename($file).</button></li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
<script>
    function select(el){
        window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(<?php echo (int)$_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'] ?>, el.getAttribute('data-name'));
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

`filebrowserUploadUrl` will be the url that handles the image upload.
Its just a standard file upload handler except you run some js on the page.
and same arguments are added to the url as with `filebrowserBrowseUrl`.

```php
<?php
... handle the upload
?>
<script>
    window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(<?php echo (int)$_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'], ', ', json_encode($uploaded_image_url), ', ', json_encode($message_on_failure) ?>);
</script>";
```

Simple Demo http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/f2ztp/show/ (upload doesn't actually work though)
http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/f2ztp/
http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/GuA6s/show/
http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/dv4-e70